# Parallelize openssl as input to dd

Tags: pipe, dd, parallelism

I am using [@tremby's great idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/172088/58343) to fill a disk with random data.

This involves piping `openssl`, which is encrypting a lot of zeros, to `dd (bs=4M)`.

I'm maxing out the single core on which this is being run (I have 7 more), and I'm nowhere near maxing out my I/O.

I'm looking for a way to parallelize the input to `dd`.

I suppose I could do it [like this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/160479/58343), but what I'm really looking for is a way to parallelize `openssl` and write that to `dd` so that the write to the disk is sequential.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: PLease, take a look at this question and see if it fits on your needs :) - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/160469/how-to-parallelize-dd

Comment: Not quite, thanks.  I was clarifying the question, but you were too fast for me!  :)

Comment: Instead of encrypting zeros why not just use random data: openssl rand 123456789

Comment: @Ole_Tange - Not sure what's faster.  The complaint over at that first link (to which tremby was responding) was that /dev/urandom was too slow; so I was taking it that the openssl method he proposed was faster and just as dependably random. Perhaps this would work just as well?

Comment: @Ole_Tange - I tried your suggestion with `openssl rand 2trillion > fifo_file &`.  Once I start reading from the fifo, the openssl process dies after about 16MB.  I didn't have through problem with @tremby's approach (linked above).

Comment: @Diagon great: I reported the bug (which is due to a 32 bit counter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important part is having a way to merge the output of your several `openssl` commands.  I believe a FIFO would solve your problem.  Try this

```
mkfifo foo
openssl <whatever your command is> > foo &
openssl <whatever your command is> > foo &
openssl <whatever your command is> > foo &
dd if=foo of=/dev/sda bs=4M
```

EDIT: Add as many of the `openssl` lines as you need to max out your system; you can even add them after `dd` invocation.

As mentioned by the OP in the comments below, it is possible to `cat foo | pv | dd of=/dev/sda` to monitor progress.

Comment: Awwwesome!  There is no *end* to learning unix.  Thanks.

Comment: IMHO named pipes (aka FIFO's) are one of the most under utilized features of Linux.  I'm here to spread the good word :)

Comment: can I `cat foo | dd` ?  I ask because if so, I can use pv to see how far I've go to go.

Comment: Sure.  You can treat foo just like any regular file except that it won't get to the end until the `openssl` commands terminate.

Comment: Now if only the debian installer would use this method during cryptsetup initialization...

Comment: @Dominik - If you don't do this already, you'll need to prepare the disks yourself, do the install, and then chroot in to fix the fstab/crypttab & update-initramfs/update-grub.  I do that on all my installs.  The installers are just not flexible enough.

Comment: @Diagon: using the text installer and manual partitioning, I don't usually prepare the disks manually. Should I? Only thing I never did was filling the disk with pseudorandom data using the slow d-i method.

Comment: @Dominik - Well, I usually do that because I want to use specific options with cryptsetup (like whirlpool or detached headers).  Also, I usually want to install using btrfs with subvolumes set up in some particular way.  It's not hard.  Just use the live usb,  prepare the disks and then run the installer.  Then you can install to the prepared disks, without doing any formatting.